# CHROME CONSOLE ERROR: Not allowed to load local resource: blob:http%3A//localhost/a44a20c1-939d-45b1-b156-9de33b86851c

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, font-awesome

I have this error message in the Chrome console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:http%3A//localhost/a44a20c1-939d-45b1-b156-9de33b86851c
```

Clicking to the right on the link just brings me to the top of the document, which does not give any clues.

When I look at the network activity, it identifies it is related to:

```
NAME: blob:http%3A//localhost/a44a20c1-939d-45b1-b156-9de33b86851c
STATUS: (blocked:other)
INITIATOR: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
```

I have no such blob file anywhere on my local machine/website.  I have have looked at my JS/Jquery code several times and can't seem to locate what coudl cause this violation and the tools in Chrome don't seem too helpful.

I use Bootstrap 4 among several other apps dependent upon Jquery.

Note - all of my code works fine, nothing seems to be broken in functionality.

**How do I get to the bottom of this error and correct/eliminate it?**

**EDIT:**  I went through some earlier code and managed to come up with this clue  on the console - seems to be associated with ***Fontawesome*** and cross-site cookie settings...but am still not sure what this means...

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:http%3A//localhost/a44a20c1-939d-45b1-b156-9de33b86851c
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://fontawesome.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032
```

Comment: You can probably get a stack trace by looking more closely at the initiator

Comment: The most probably the problem is in encoding your `:` sign after http - the correct url should be `blob:http://localhost/...` `%3A` -> `:`

Comment: I am not referencing this blob anywhere in my code - I don't know what program could be referencing it - maybe one of the third party apps that use Jquery...